# Textpad GCC Compiling C

Tags: c, gcc, textpad

I'm attempting to compile my program in C using gcc.exe from the MinGW package that I have installed.  I have added gcc as an external tool and am able to run it through TextPad.  However, I'm getting generic error messages such as "Tool completed with exit code 1".  Is there any way to configure TextPad/gcc to display the correct error messages as it would in a command prompt unix environment?

Comment: I think that tutorial http://www.edparrish.net/common/textpad4c.html can be useful.

Comment: If you don't get what you want from TextPad, eclipse works very well in Windows with mingw gcc.